# Creating an html template that looks like windown but have problems with the resizers

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm creating an windown look like template for web but I have a problem with the resizer, the resizer in the bottom right works perfectly but trying to create the top right resizer don't work and I don't know why I have tried everything but it doesn't work.

The window don't resize well when you drag the resizer in the top right. it moves really weird. https://alhazacod.github.io/windowsxphtmltemplate try it for yourself.

Here's the Github https://github.com/alhazacod/windowsxphtmltemplate

The JavaScript code:

```
dragru.onmousedown = function(event) {
  let shiftLeft = event.clientX - wwindow.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  let shiftTop = event.clientY - wwindow.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  let shiftBottom = - event.clientY + wwindow.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

  function resize(w, h, pageY){
    wwindow.style.top = pageY - shiftTop + 'px';
    if(w>200){
      wwindow.style.width = w + 'px';
    }
    if(h>200){
      console.log(wwindow.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - event.pageY);
      wwindow.style.height = (wwindow.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - event.pageY) + 'px';

    }
    //wwindow.style.top = pageY - shiftTop + 'px';
  }

  function onMouseMove(event){
    shiftLeft = event.clientX - wwindow.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    shiftBottom = -event.clientY + wwindow.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
    //if(event.pageY < windowh && event.pageY > 1 && event.pageX < windoww && event.pageX > 1){
      resize(shiftLeft, shiftBottom, event.pageY);
    //}
    /*else{
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
      wwindow.onmouseup = null;
    }*/
  }

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

  wwindow.onmouseup = function(){
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    wwindow.onmouseup = null;
  };
};
```

Comment: "windown look like" means "Windows look-alike"?

Comment: I would expect the code for `dragrd` and `dragru` to be very similar - it's not

Comment: you need to increase or reduce `height` while also reducing or increasing `top` or `transformX` respectively

Comment: Sorry for the error i am not a native speaker @kshetline

Comment: Yest the code is very similar you can check it on the github but i think i reply too late, thanks for help me @Bravo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change dragru to the following code and it works

```
dragru.onmousedown = function (event) {
    let bottom = wwindow.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
    let left = wwindow.getBoundingClientRect().left;

    function resize(w, h) {
        if (w > 200) {
            wwindow.style.width = w + 'px';
        }
        if (h > 200) {
            wwindow.style.top = bottom - h + 'px';
            wwindow.style.height = h + 'px';
        }
    }

    function onMouseMove(event) {
        if (event.pageY < windowh && event.pageY > 1 && event.pageX < windoww && event.pageX > 1)
            resize(event.clientX - left, bottom - event.clientY);
        else {
            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            wwindow.onmouseup = null;
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

    wwindow.onmouseup = function () {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        wwindow.onmouseup = null;
    };
};
```

---

> Added snippet to show it works (adjusted minimum height/width of window to prevent jumps when initially sizing due to the initial size of the "window")

```js
wwindow = document.querySelectorAll(".window")[0];
windoww = document.querySelectorAll(".desktop")[0].offsetWidth - 1;
windowh = document.querySelectorAll(".desktop")[0].offsetHeight - 45;
dragrd = wwindow.querySelectorAll(".drag-rd")[0];
dragru = wwindow.querySelectorAll(".drag-ru")[0];

dragwindow = wwindow.querySelectorAll(".title")[0];
window.addEventListener('click', function (e) {});

dragwindow.onmousedown = function (event) {
    let shiftX = event.clientX - wwindow.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    let shiftY = event.clientY - wwindow.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    wwindow.style.zIndex = 10;

    windoww = document.querySelectorAll(".desktop")[0].offsetWidth - 1;
    windowh = document.querySelectorAll(".desktop")[0].offsetHeight - 45;

    function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
        wwindow.style.left = pageX - shiftX + 'px';
        wwindow.style.top = pageY - shiftY + 'px';
    }

    function onMouseMove(event) {
        if (event.pageY < windowh && event.pageY > 1 && event.pageX < windoww && event.pageX > 1)
            moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);
        else {
            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            wwindow.onmouseup = null;
        }
    }

    // move the wwindow on mousemove
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

    // drop the wwindow, remove unneeded handlers
    wwindow.onmouseup = function () {
        wwindow.style.zIndex = 9;
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        wwindow.onmouseup = null;
    };
};

dragrd.onmousedown = function (event) {
    let {top, left} = wwindow.getBoundingClientRect();
    function resize(w, h) {
        if (w > 150) {
            wwindow.style.width = w + 'px';
        }
        if (h > 50) {
            wwindow.style.height = h + 'px';
        }
    }

    function onMouseMove(event) {
        if (event.pageY < windowh && event.pageY > 1 && event.pageX < windoww && event.pageX > 1)
            resize(event.clientX - left, event.clientY - top);
        else {
            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            wwindow.onmouseup = null;
        }
    }

    function onMouseUp () {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        wwindow.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
    };

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    wwindow.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
};


dragru.onmousedown = function (event) {
    let {bottom, left} = wwindow.getBoundingClientRect();

    function resize(w, h) {
        if (w > 150) {
            wwindow.style.width = w + 'px';
        }
        if (h > 50) {
            wwindow.style.top = bottom - h + 'px';
            wwindow.style.height = h + 'px';

        }
    }

    function onMouseMove(event) {
        if (event.pageY < windowh && event.pageY > 1 && event.pageX < windoww && event.pageX > 1)
            resize(event.clientX - left, bottom - event.clientY);
        else {
            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            wwindow.onmouseup = null;
        }
    }

    function onMouseUp () {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        wwindow.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
    };

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    wwindow.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
};
```

```css
.dropup-content{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 32px;
    left: -2px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropup-show{
    display: block;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

*{
    font-family: tahoma;
}

.bg{
    background-image: url("../public/winxpwallpaper.jpg");
    background-color: darkslategrey;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.cover{
    height: 100%;
}

.no-padding{
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.no-margin{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.no-select {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
      -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
       -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
         -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
          -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
              user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                    supported by Chrome, Opera and Firefox */
  }

/*navbar styles*/

.no-margin-navbar{
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
    margin-left: -7px;
}

.navbar{
    background-color: #265DDC;
    /*Shadow*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -4px 16px -1px rgba(0,0,0,1); 
    box-shadow: 0px -4px 16px -1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    /*Inset Shadow*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 10px -1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3); 
    box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 10px -1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

.start-btn{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropup-content{
    height: 60vh;
    width: 30vw;
    min-width: 400px !important;
    padding: 3px;
    border-top-left-radius: 1%;
    border-top-right-radius: 1%;

    background: rgba(19,97,199,1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,97,199,1) 0%, rgba(107,172,247,1) 23%, rgba(107,172,247,1) 79%, rgba(19,97,199,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(19,97,199,1)), color-stop(23%, rgba(107,172,247,1)), color-stop(79%, rgba(107,172,247,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(19,97,199,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,97,199,1) 0%, rgba(107,172,247,1) 23%, rgba(107,172,247,1) 79%, rgba(19,97,199,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,97,199,1) 0%, rgba(107,172,247,1) 23%, rgba(107,172,247,1) 79%, rgba(19,97,199,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,97,199,1) 0%, rgba(107,172,247,1) 23%, rgba(107,172,247,1) 79%, rgba(19,97,199,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(19,97,199,1) 0%, rgba(107,172,247,1) 23%, rgba(107,172,247,1) 79%, rgba(19,97,199,1) 100%);

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 2px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.31); 
    box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 2px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.31);
}

.start-title{
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    margin: 5px;
}

.start-title>div{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.start-title-img{
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 7%;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background: #CECECE;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #CECECE 0%, #8C8C8C 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #CECECE 0%, #8C8C8C 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #CECECE 0%, #8C8C8C 100%);
}

.start-title-img>img{
    border-radius: 7%;
    background-color: grey;
}

.start-linklist-left{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 75%;
    overflow: scroll;
    margin-right: -4px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    vertical-align: top;
}
.start-linklist-right{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 75%;
    overflow: scroll;
    margin-right: -4px;
    background-color: rgb(203, 227, 255);
    vertical-align: top;
}

.start-span{
    background: #CECECE;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #CECECE 15%, #FF7B00 50%, #CECECE 85%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #CECECE 15%, #FF7B00 50%, #CECECE 85%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #CECECE 15%, #FF7B00 50%, #CECECE 85%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
}

.start-footer{
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
.start-option{
    padding: 8px;
}

.start-option{
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.start-link:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
  
.start-link:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.start-link:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.start-link:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.start-option:hover{
    background-color: #265DDC;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.start-option > *{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.window{

    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 40%;
    height: 30%;

    background: rgba(107,172,247,1);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(107,172,247,1) 0%, rgba(107,172,247,1) 0%, rgba(19,97,199,1) 66%, rgba(19,97,199,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(107,172,247,1)), color-stop(0%, rgba(107,172,247,1)), color-stop(66%, rgba(19,97,199,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(19,97,199,1)));
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(107,172,247,1) 0%, rgba(107,172,247,1) 0%, rgba(19,97,199,1) 66%, rgba(19,97,199,1) 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(107,172,247,1) 0%, rgba(107,172,247,1) 0%, rgba(19,97,199,1) 66%, rgba(19,97,199,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(107,172,247,1) 0%, rgba(107,172,247,1) 0%, rgba(19,97,199,1) 66%, rgba(19,97,199,1) 100%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(107,172,247,1) 0%, rgba(107,172,247,1) 0%, rgba(19,97,199,1) 66%, rgba(19,97,199,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6bacf7', endColorstr='#1361c7', GradientType=1 );
    
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 17px 6px -17px rgba(107,172,247,1); 
    box-shadow: inset 0px 17px 6px -17px rgba(107,172,247,1);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
.window>.title{
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    cursor: grab
}
.window>.title>.img{
    height: 80%;
    margin-top: -2px;
}
.window>.content{
    
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
}
.window>.drag-rd{
    background-color: red;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    top: calc(100% - 5px);
    left: calc(100% - 5px);
    position: absolute;
    cursor: se-resize;
}
.window>.drag-ru{
    background-color: red;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    top: -5px;
    left: calc(100% - 5px);
    position: absolute;
    cursor: ne-resize;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-light no-padding no-margin-navbar no-select">
        <div class="dropup no-margin-navbar">
            <div href="" onclick="toggleUp()" class="start-btn no-padding">
                <img src="public/winxpstart.png" width="110" height="35" alt="" class="start-btn no-margin-navbar">
            </div>
            <div class="dropup-content" id = "start-content">
                <div class="start-title">
                    <div class="start-title-img"><img src="public/chess.bmp" alt=""></div>
                    <div><b>User</b></div>
                </div>
                <div class="start-span"></div>
                <div class="start-linklist-left">
                    <a class="start-link" href="">
                        <div class="start-option">
                            <img width="30" src="public/Internet_Explorer_6_logo.png" alt="">
                            Internet Explorer
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a class="start-link" href="">
                        <div class="start-option">
                            <img width="30" src="public/Internet_Explorer_6_logo.png" alt="">
                            Internet Explorer
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a class="start-link" href="">
                        <div class="start-option">
                            <img width="30" src="public/Internet_Explorer_6_logo.png" alt="">
                            Internet Explorer
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="start-linklist-right">
                    <div class="start-option">
                        <img width="30" src="public/Internet_Explorer_6_logo.png" alt="">
                        <a class="start-link" href="">opcion 1</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="start-footer">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="desktop" class="bg desktop">
        <div id="window" class="window">
            <div class="title no-select" id="windowTitle"><img class="img" src="public/Internet_Explorer_6_logo.png" alt=""> Hola mundo</div>
            <div class="drag-rd"></div>
            <div class="drag-ru"></div>
            <div class="content">
                Hello
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```